# Spring Cache Abstraction with Custom Cache Manager

Tags: java, spring, caching

I am looking for caching solution that implements the org.springframework.cache.CacheManager other than ehcache. If there exist such solution, how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new caching library so called [imcache](https://github.com/Cetsoft/imcache). This library supports CacheManager of the spring by imcache-spring project. An example use of this library can be found at this [blog](http://www.yusufaytas.com/spring-cache-abstraction/).

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search for "implementations of org.springframework.cache.CacheManager" provides a number of results.

For example: http://www.captaindebug.com/2012/09/spring-31-caching-and-config.html#.UsyJ6fZOvQY

Or you could write your own.